# NA not permitted in predictors. missForest

Tags: r, random-forest, imputation

I am using `missForest` in order to impute missing data. I have the data as a data frame and when I put it into the `missForest` function I get the error:

> Error in randomForest.default(x = obsX, y = obsY, ntree = ntree, mtry = mtry,  :  NA not permitted in predictors

However, since I do not have predictors I am just trying to impute I do not know where this comes from. The code below should reproduce the problem with a sample data set.

The code below is a simulated version of my problem. However, I have already tried to convert Y into a data frame and I get the same error.

```
Y <- prodNA(matrix(as.character(runif(100) > 0.5), nrow=10))
missForest(Y)
```

Comment: missForest can not handle character input as far as I know. This is why your example does not work. Think you need either numeric or factor input.

Comment: My data is in a mixed factor and numeric format and I get the error message of "invalid first argument". However, when my data type is only numeric missForest works properly. The only thing I can find is putting it into the data frame format inside missForest but even when I do that it does not work.

Comment: Hard to guess what the problem with this new error message is. Perhaps I can help you if you provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I changed all character columns into factors by:

```
df = data.frame(apply(df, 2, as.factor))
```

and that solved my error.
As Steffen Moritz said, missforest needs either numeric or factor input.

Answer (score 0):

You need that your variables are factor type, do the transformation and try again